# how to locate active file in NERDTree quickly

Tags: vim, nerdtree

say, I'm editing a file called application_controller.rb, which in `~/work/foo/app/controller/`.

Now I want to open NERDTree window, and hope it can automatically expand the folder `~/work/foo/app/controller/`, and position the cursor at the file `application_controller.rb`. How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:NERDTreeFind` is most probably what you're looking for:

```
Find the current file in the tree.

If not tree exists and the current file is under vim's CWD, then init a
tree at the CWD and reveal the file. Otherwise init a tree in the current
file's directory.
```